# System.DllNotFoundException: sqlcipher release build Xamarin

Tags: android, exception, xamarin.android, xamarin

While building my application for release in Xamarin Studio (Monodroid) i'm getting a "System.DllNotFoundException: sqlcipher" exception. This means the app can not find the sqlcipher DLL.

This issue only appears in release mode. Under the setting "Android build", i have tried several things like:

- Embed assemblies in native code
- Link all assemblies

But the application is still crashing on release mode. Anything i could have missed?

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack trace? Do you get this exception when running the application on the device, or when building, or when packaging?

Comment: I'm getting this exception when i run the application. The build and package process goes well. When i extract the APK the sqlcipher dll is also there, but the app can not find it. The exception: http://snipt.org/Bahae1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got a answer back from Xamarin support:

> If so, the problem is that the SqlCipher component does not contain
>   armeabi libraries, only armeabi-v7a and x86 [0]. Consequently, it
>   can't be used on any armeabi (ARMv5) platforms, which includes all
>   ARM-based Android emulators before API-14 (which is the first emulator
>   that uses armeabi-v7a).
>
> If you need to test on API-10, try using the x86 emulator or an
>   armeabi-v7a hardware device.

We tried this solution before we contacted Xamarin support, but it didn't work. The solution was to change the project to armeabi-v7a and restart the IDE. Weird, but true.